# Where is Image with Text Overlay file in Shopify located?

Tags: sass, shopify, liquid, shopify-app, liquid-layout

I am new to Shopify. I want to add an option to change the colour of the text, change the background colour and text colour  in the button in the Image with text overlay section. How do I do that and where is the code for this component located in Shopify?
Here is the component I wish to change:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

For CSS you may find `theme.scss.liquid`. In the `customize` section you can change the text and for custom edit there are templates and sections for that. 
Please inspect through browser  the section id you will find the section and search accordingly.